# revert minmax normalization back to original value

Tags: networking, normalize

i'm training a neural network. Normalization of inputs and outputs (training data) are carried out using min Max to a scale of [0-1].

I'm applying backpropagation learning algorithm. Firstly, i need to get the error offset. i.e. error = actual output - output

how do i scale my output [0-1] back to actual real values such as in zero to thousands range?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem which the actual output is a real value between 0 and 1000 the fist thing you need to do is choose the right measure of your error.
For example mean square error is a common choice.

Then you need to know that NN is normally used as a classifier meaning it tells you if the predict is true or false. Your problem seems to be a regression problem rather than a classification problem.

If you want to use NN, it actually can be used to do regression, I would

1. First map your output (0-1000) to (0-1) by dividing 1000
2. Choose mean square as your cost function
3. Train you NN to learn the weights
4. Apply the NN to your test set and calculate the mean square